# Rubisco and Nitrogen Shortage Condition

Tags: plant-physiology

Suppose a plant sprouted when $t=0$ and died when $t=T$. Let $t_*$ be the time when the plant shifts the resources usage to maximize its reproductive organ. In the case of nitrogen shortage during plant growth, it is known that $t_*$ becomes earlier. Would someone please explain this phenomenon by relating to Rubisco?

Here are some of my findings:

- It was shown that the decrease in the amount of Rubisco during leaf
  senescence is higher compared to plants grown under suboptimal
  N‐feeding conditions (Tercé‐Laforgue et al., 2004).
- Rubisco is also considered as one of the most important Nitrogen
  source that can potentially be remobilized and translocated to growing
  or storage organs.

Currently, I understand how the nitrogen shortage is related to Rubisco, but I still do not how to relate this to the prioritization of reproductive organ. This might be a mere uneducated guess, but does this have something to do with survival of the plant? Say, it senses that Rubisco itself cannot replace the needed amount of nitrogen, then it is wiser for the plant to reproduce rather than growing.